# After npm run deploy errors occured

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, npm, github-pages

After npm run deploy i have errors like above
 [Repo on Github](https://github.com/lukasz9210/hello-world-4)

I am trying to deploy my react-app on gh-pages on Github (create-react-app)

```
'gh-pages' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world-4@0.1.0 deploy: `npm run build&&gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world-4@0.1.0 deploy script 'npm run build&&gh-page
s -d build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hello-world-4 package
,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build&&gh-pages -d build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hello-world-4
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hello-world-4
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-12T17_55_00_56
9Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is `gh-pages`?: `npm run build&&gh-pages -d build`

Comment: gh-pages is a npm library which is useful for deploying codes on github. Follow this link [https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom]=(https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom)

Answer (score 12):

[image: I got the error like this]

So I run this command `npm install --save gh-pages`

like below

[image: Run the command like this]

After that I run the command `npm run deploy`

My code published successfully like below.

[image: My code published successfully]

For more details just follow this link by Facebook which is given below.

(https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom)

I hope your issue will be resolved. In case of error please reply.

Answer (score 5):

please install `gh-pages` and it ready to go

To install

```
npm install gh-pages
```

to deploy

add this to `package.json`

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
 
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

and then this

```
npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

gh pages stands for GitHub Pages. It is simply a way to deploy a website via a github repo. Basically, NPM is yelling because when it attempts to run the command deploy, there is not link or reference to the line

```
$npm run build&&gh-pages -d build
```

You need make sure that `gh-pages -d build` is defined. A place to start would be running `gh-pages --man` or `gh-pages --help`

Answer (score 1):

I facing the same problem I do the following command before
`git push`
not working. After

`git push`

I do the same command it works correctly.

`npm install gh-pages`

and deploy

`npm run deploy`